Wait for datasource to load in Angular
I have some dynamic content being loaded in the html, using material tables, and linking the datasource to a signal, like this:
    <table
      mat-table
      [dataSource]="[resultEntries$()][0]"
      (contentChanged)="scrollToFourth()"
    >
      <ng-container matColumnDef="col-lemma">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <a
            [id]="element.alpha"
            class="link-primary"
            role="button"
            (click)="clickID(element)"
            >{{ element.l }}</a
          >
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="col-brp">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.bp }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="col-amp">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.ap }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr
        mat-row
        class="material-row"
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
      ></tr>
    </table>

And I need to run this function, in which I use the oldfashioned getElementById to access the DOM element (I've tried ViewChild to no avail).
  scrollToFourth(): void {
    let delayInMilliseconds = 50;
    while (!this.resultEntry$()[0].alpha) {
      setTimeout(() => {}, delayInMilliseconds);
    }
    document
      .getElementById(this.resultEntry$()[0].alpha.toString())!
      .scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'instant',
      });
  }

The problem is that it runs too early, and it gives me an error saying that the DOM element doesn't exist. If I move everything into ngAfterViewInit, it's still too early. The only way it works is to put it inside a setTimeout with a four-second delay, but of course, the exact number of seconds will depend on the client and server, so this is hardly a good alternative.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If your're using signal as data source, why not use "effects".  It's true that you need enclosed the action in a setTimeout -without delay time- to say to Angular: "hey, change the data source and, when you finished of draw remember that you need makes this another sentences"
  readonly dataSource = signal(ELEMENT_DATA);
  @ViewChild('id') el!:ElementRef
  constructor(){
    effect(()=>{
      const dataSource=this.dataSource();
      //the setTimeout it's only to makes the actions after "repaint"
      //but see that have no "delay time"
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'instant',
        });
      })
    })
  }

stackblitz

Beautiful. Thanks. It worked like a charm. If I put the effect(()=> outside the constructor, putting this code in a component's method, it still works as intended, but the console throws an error saying that effect can only be used inside a constructor. Is there a way to achieve the same result when I need to change the datasource without loading the entire the component again?

To create an effect outside of the constructor, you can pass an Injector to effect via its options  see the docs. Sorry, what do you want to say when write "Is there a way to achieve the same result when I need to change the datasource without loading the entire the component again?" See that when you want to change a signal you use "set" or "update", but you need take careful when is an array you need send a "new array", generally you use spread operator, e.g. :this.data.puhs("new");this.data=[...this.data]
